# Why the error "Undefined Index" appears

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When i made a simple student registration page, i gave some input values to the fields and tried to exho those values simply by using POST. 
But it shows "Undefined Variable"

Below is my code for making a simple student registration form.

```
                            <head>

                                            <title>Student's Registration Form</title>

                            </head>

                            <body>
```

Student's Registration Form  

                                                

                                                

                                                Student's Name:

                                                

                                                



                                                

                                                Father's Name:

                                                

                                                



                                                

                                                School's Name:

                                                

                                                



                                                

                                                Roll No:

                                                

                                                



                                                

                                                Class:

                                                

                                                

                                                Select Class

                                                10th

                                                9th

```
                            </body>
```

Comment: Please add your code for us.

Comment: show you code ... and show your exact error message

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, have a quick look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: however, this for sure will help: [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”, “Notice: Undefined index”, and “Notice: Undefined offset”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef?rq=1)

Comment: `But it shows "Undefined Variable"`. It's not so hard to conclude why. You just need to un-lazy yourself. First, what's an index? Simply put, it's the name you're accessing in `$_POST`. If you're accessing `$_POST['name']`, `'name'` is the index. If it's undefined, it means it's not there. Therefore, you get the error. See how **trivial** it is? All you have to do is take a deep breath, read the message, read your code, read your input, conclude what you did wrong.

Comment: @KrisRoofe hello , please find my code below. Thanks

Comment: <html>                                  <head>                                                  <title>Student's Registration Form</title>                                  </head>                                  <body>  <form method='post' action='user_registration'.php>  <table width='500' border='3' align='center'>                                                                                                   <tr>

Comment: @KrisRoofe <th bgcolor = 'yellow' colspan='5'>Student's Registration Form</th>                                                    </tr>                                                  <tr>                                                  <td align = 'right'>Student's Name:</td>                                                  <td><input type = 'text' name = 'user_name'></td>                                                  </tr>                                                                                                   <tr>

Comment: @KrisRoofe <td align = 'right'>Father's Name:</td>                                                  <td><input type='text' name = 'father_name'></td>                                                  </tr>                                                                                                   <tr>                                                  <td align = 'right'>School's Name:</td>                                                  <td><input type = 'text' name='school_name'</td>

Comment: </tr>                                                                                                   <tr>                                                  <td align = 'right'>Roll No:</td>                                                  <td><input type='text' name = 'roll_no'</td>                                                  </tr>                                                                                                   <tr>                                                  <td align = 'right'>Class:</td>

Comment: <td>                                                  <select name = 'student_class'>                                                  <option value = 'null'>Select Class</option>                                                  <option value = '10th'>10th</option>                                                  <option value = '9th'>9th</option>                                                  </select>                                                  </td>

Comment: @KrisRoofe </tr>                                                  <tr>                                                  <td align = 'center' colspan = '6'>                                                  <input type='submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Submit'>                                                  </td>                                                  </tr>                                                                                                   </table>                                                                                                    </form>

Comment: @KrisRoofe </body>                                                                                                                                                                      </html>     <?php     $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  $db = mysql_select_db('students', $conn);

Comment: @KrisRoofe $student_name = $_POST['user_name'];                   $student_father = $_POST['father_name'];                   $student_school = $_POST['school_name'];                   $student_roll = $_POST['roll_no'];                   $student_class = $_POST['student_class'];                   ?>

Answer (score 0):

Its undefined because you haven't declared the variable or accessing the array using the undefined index.

you need to access array element as

```
if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
  echo $array[$key];
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Currently I cannot comment :D

Comment: Sorry for it, I gorget it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15637933)

Comment: @suraj At the time I commented I didn't have enough reputation :) so I had to post answer